# If MYSQL field A is equal to MYSQL field B then print MYSQL field C

Tags: php, mysql

I want to print the content of a table called 'res_properties' to get an overview about my portfolio, but no idea about the syntax (PHP knows me, but I don'know PHP...):

I have a table called 'res_properties' and a column called 'location_id' and
I have another table called 'res_location' and 2 columns called 'id' and 'slug'
where column 'slug' contains the human readable content of the location

Sample
'id' is "3" equal to "California" (content of 'slug")
'id' is "4" equal to "Virginia" (content of 'slug") 
etc.

When printing out I need to lookup table 'res_location' and when 'location_id' is equal to 'id' 
then replace 'id' with the content of 'slug' (or move the content of 'slug' into a new field e.g. 'location_name' (25 chars.) and print that field.

So far my code is this an I appreciate any help. Many thanks:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Portfolio</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../scripts/css/formate.css" />
<body>

<?php 
 // Connects to Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost","user","passw") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM res_properties"); 
 $location = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM res_locations")

 or die(mysql_error()); 

 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 Print "<br><h3>Portfolio</h3><p><br>"; 
   Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
   Print "<tr align='left'><th width=130>Villa Name</th><th width=40>Beds</th><th width=40>Baths</th><th width=60>Sleeps</th><th width=40>Location</th><th width=40>Loc-ID</th><th width=300 >Site URL</th></tr>"; 

   while($info2 = mysql_fetch_array( $location )) 
   while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 

 { 

 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<td>".$info['ref_id'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<td>".$info['bedrooms'] . " </td>"; 
 Print "<td>".$info['bathrooms'] . " </td>"; 
 Print "<td>".$info['max_occupants'] . " </td>"; 
 Print "<td>".$info2['slug'] . " </td>"; 
 Print "<td>".$info2['id'] . " </td>"; 

// here I want to print a clickable URL but some syntax error:
// Print "<td>" http://www.domain_name.com/'.$info['slug'] .'.html;

// when using the echo command it works fine like this, but doesn't output a clickable URL:
// echo 'http://www.domain_name.com/'.$info['slug'] .'.html' . "<br />"; 


 } 
 Print "</table>"; 
 ?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to print the content of the tables res_properties and res_locations. The table res_properties contains properties which are located in certain states. In your output you want to print the properties and the states in which the properties are located. The best way to do that is to [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) your tables res_properties and res_locations in a single sql statement using the column location_id of res_properties and the column id of res_locations:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM res_properties t1 INNER JOIN res_locations t2 ON t1.location_id = t2.id");
```

With the join statement mysql returns a single joined table containing the whole information corresponding to a single property. Now iterate the $data and print the values:

```
print "<table>";
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
   print "<tr>"; 
   print "<td>" . $info['ref_id'] . "</td> "; 
   print "<td>" . $info['bedrooms'] . "</td>"; 
   print "<td>" . $info['bathrooms'] . "</td>"; 
   print "<td>" . $info['max_occupants'] . "</td>"; 
   print "<td>" . $info['slug'] . "</td>"; 
   print "<td>" . $info['id'] . "</td>";
   print "<td>http://www.domain_name.com/" . $info['slug'] . ".html</td>";
}
print "</table>";
```

To understand php better try to think about the semantics of your two successive while loops:

```
while($info2 = mysql_fetch_array( $location )) 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{
```

Also take care to use proper php syntax in your [print](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) statements to avoid syntax errors! For example to print plain string values, parantheses are necessary:

```
print "hello world";
```

I hope my code is free of syntax errors and that I answered your question.

Comment: Joel - You're THE MAN !

Perfectly understood, implemented your code, syntax error-free and works like a charm !!! I'm getting exited now, since I have all the data at hand to print a complete detailed list !

Comment: The only thing I'm looking for is that clickable URL, which I have to put together from:
web address fix: www.domain-name/
DB-field retrieved: xxxxxx  (field is named 'slug')
Html ending fix :  .html

The clickable URL when constructed should look like this: www.domain-name/xxxxxx.html

Can I ask you once more for your help please ?

Many, many thanks !

Comment: Well thats easy. To have a clickable url you just have to use the a tag of html: print "<td><a href=\"hostnamewithhttpinfrontofit/" . $info['slug'] . ".html\">This is now some clickable text.</a></td>"; For more info about the a tag visit: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp.

Comment: Thanks @joel ! Works fine as well. I got a clickable URL!
But I I think I need to safe the content of the column . $info['slug'] . before joining the tables. It contains now the human readable location name (and puts it before .html).

BTW: I don't want to waste too much of your time, but one more question please and then I'm done: 
In order to print a thumbnail of the property, could I join one more table 'res_images' with column 'id' and coloumn 'filename' into this sql statement:

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM res_properties t1 INNER JOIN res_locations t2 ON t1.location_id = t2.id");

Comment: Sure. You can join as many tables as you want. However if you continue to add and add and add and add more tables to the join statement at some point you will have a performance issue ;). Following sql statement should work: `$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (res_properties t1 INNER JOIN res_locations t2 ON t1.location_id = t2.id) INNER JOIN res_images t3 ON t1.location_id = t3.id");` I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks again - That works also ! But it prints the NAME of the image, instead of the image itself. How is the definition, to print the image please ?
My last post contains 2 questions. Can you get back to the first part please, where I said: I think I need to safe the content of the column . $info['slug'] . before joining the tables. It contains now the human readable location name (and puts it before .html). --> thus creating a wrong URL ! SORRY, but if I stop asking at his moment, your valuable support would have been in vain...

Comment: To print you image you have to use the `img` tag of html (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp). Just access with $info the proper column which stores the name of the image. As long as everything you need is in your database tables you do not have to store anything before joining the tables. Choose in your sql-select statement the columns which you want to pass to your data variable and which you want to access with your info variable. If you want to build a bigger application maybe you should do a step back and read about SQL and HTML.

Comment: The img tag ...- That's it - as simple as that! - stupid me ! 
I'm getting exited when I look at my (your!) output. Thanks again for all you support joel.

Comment: Well. You are welcome. Do not forget to mark a reply as an answer which answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to read the body of your question but if the title is accurate, then this might be what you want.

```
SELECT IF(table.fieldA = table.fieldB, table.fieldC, NULL) FROM table;
```

Format is IF(condition,output if true, output if false)

Now if my answer is on the right track but not quite right and you tell me, I will update it.

Comment: Buttle Butkus - English is not my native language and yes I agree, not easy to understand what I meant, but found a solution (below). Thank you too for your support ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use joins in mysql, then you don't need to worry about PHP script, use the following sql query to fetch the data

```
$data = mysql_query("select
rl.id,
rl.slug
from res_location as rl
join res_properties as rp on rp.location_id=rl.id");
```

[Follow my Blog at w3easystep.info](http://w3easystep.info)

Comment: Srihari Goud
Thank you too ! When I tried joels advise it works perfect!